# Comparing negative numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, comparison, numbers

I'm sure this is a simple problem, but I'm comparing negative numbers in javascript i.e.:

```
var num1 = -83.778;
var num2 = -83.356;

if(num1 < num2)
{
    // Take action 1
}
else
{
    // Take action 2
}
```

This script will always take action 2, even though `num1` is less than `num2`.  Whats going on here?

Comment: This works for me. `>>> -83.778 < -83.356 -> true`.  Platform / JS Version / Browser version?

Comment: Hi, I tested myself, and it take the action 1. There nothing wrong about the comparing here. Maybe your code is wrong somewhere else

Comment: Are you sure that's all there is to it? [It works for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/BVN6T/)

Comment: no, it is behaving properly with me.can you please check it again

Comment: I just pasted this code into my javascript console and it works exactly as you would expect it to.  You must have some other bug...

Comment: OK, then I must be doing something completely stupid here.  Thanks

Comment: This works for me. Perhaps you need to give us more context? How exactly is this chunk of code being used/called?

Comment: Could you paste your entire code? Including "action 1" and "action 2."

Answer (score 25, accepted):

How does `if (parseFloat(num1) < parseFloat(num2))` work? Maybe your numbers are turning into strings somewhere.

Comment: exactly.  I was getting the numbers from a JSON response and not parsing them back into floats.

Haha sorry everyone....

Comment: Really, JS was comparing two strings with the negative values, thanks for that answer.

Answer (score 0):

This case also works when we want to compare signed characters for both positive and negative numbers. For my case i had numbers like +3, +4, 0, -1 etc.. 

Directly using `if(num1 > num2)` would compare these values as string and we would get output of string comparision. 

Thus to compare signed numbers., compare them via `if (parseFloat(num1) < parseFloat(num2))`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Workaround for that:

```
var num1 = -83.778;
var num2 = -83.356;
if((num1 - num2) < 0)
{
    // Take action 1
}
else
{
    // Take action 2
}
```

Now Ation 1 will be used.